# Svg path position

Tags: html, svg

I have an SVG path, defined as follows:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="200px"
height="280px" viewBox="0 0 850.39 850.39"
enable-background="new 0 0 850.39 850.39" xml:space="preserve" class="hand">
  <g>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#0D0D0D" d="M480.366,674.977c-1.345-36.176,16.102-91.082,42.928-100.447
      s99.269-89.711,108.649-100.418c9.381-10.734,14.758-17.416,24.139-45.541c9.409-28.123,54.996-69.638,54.996-69.638
      c18.79-20.072,36.236-25.44,45.616-25.44c9.381,0,29.515-5.368,34.863-14.733c5.377-9.365,6.721-30.779-26.826-44.199
      c-33.519-13.362-54.997-24.098-127.411,36.176c-72.442,60.245-97.925,3.997-97.925,3.997c-30.859-54.877-16.102-137.906,0-199.522
      c16.102-61.587,20.105-172.74,12.069-190.157c-8.037-17.389-34.12-19.33-45.617-10.707c-12.212,9.193-22.793,89.739-32.174,124.544
      c-9.409,34.805-25.482,97.763-25.482,97.763c-4.032,42.856-36.236,28.124-46.96,20.072c-10.725-8.023-17.446-73.636-16.102-84.343
      c1.344-10.735,0-41.515-1.344-49.566c-1.315-8.023-21.45-97.762-25.482-128.542c-4.004-33.492-29.515-40.173-42.928-38.831
      c-13.384,1.313-22.794,13.391-22.794,25.44c0,12.049,9.41,115.151,6.721,123.203c-2.688,8.023,1.344,73.636,6.692,83.029
      c1.344,12.049,9.38,68.268,4.032,70.952c-5.348,2.684-17.446-13.391-25.482-38.831c-8.065-25.44-24.138-73.636-24.138-73.636
      c-9.409-21.443-14.757-79.032-20.134-104.472c-5.348-25.44-20.105-34.805-38.895-32.15c-16.102,2.684-26.827,28.152-24.138,40.202
      c5.348,9.365,18.761,155.323,24.138,167.373c5.348,12.049,26.826,80.345,25.482,85.713c-1.344,5.339-8.065,8.023-20.134,3.998
      c-12.041-3.998-71.07-113.809-71.07-113.809c-21.45-37.489-25.482-72.323-60.374-57.59c-22.793,12.049-9.38,34.833-4.004,57.59
      c8.037,36.147,84.512,166.059,79.135,180.792c-5.377,14.733,28.17,176.737,28.17,176.737c0,26.783,65.722,156.695,68.381,164.719
      c2.717,8.051,2.145,84.17,0,113.836c-1.916,27.012-6.635,164.547-9.123,239.324c-0.257,8.023,2.431,15.018,8.037,20.785
      c5.577,5.768,12.498,8.709,20.534,8.709H469.87c8.265,0,15.387-3.111,20.992-9.164c5.634-6.082,8.179-13.42,7.521-21.643
      C490.919,872.699,481.396,702.414,480.366,674.977L480.366,674.977z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

I need to give this path an absolute position. I have tried setting `cx` and `cy` attributes, but this did not work.

What can I do to set an absolute position?

Comment: This answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479591/svg-positioning

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Use the `transform` attribute to position the path, like

```
transform="translate(50,80)"
```

Other transformations like `scale` or `rotate` are also available. [See the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#EstablishingANewUserSpace).

Comment: This does not work in my case whether by inline style or CSS https://codepen.io/jarrodwhitley/pen/pooYgLN

Comment: This is not a style attribute or CSS, it's a transform attribute.

Comment: Specifically, the `transform` attribute of the SVG itself.

Comment: I could not take a spec like that and give a helpful, precise answer like you did; at least not in a reasonable amount of time. I would like to be able to do that, though. Do I need to become a domain expert or are there tricks on how to parse specs more quickly?

Comment: What specs? Just read up on how to use SVG elements, MDN has plenty of information there.

Answer (score 13):

I have a tool to do this at: http://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg_transforms
Just paste the individual element you want to change in the box and select 'Absolute' from the Path Type option.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200px" height="280px" viewBox="250 300 400 400">
  <g>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#0D0D0D" d="M480.37 674.98S579.64 585.27 589.02 574.56C598.4 563.82 603.77 557.14 613.15 529.02C622.56 500.9 668
    .15 459.38 668.15 459.38C686.94 439.31 704.39 433.94 713.77 433.94C723.15 433.94 743.28 428.57 748.63 419.21C754.01 409.84 755.35 388.43 721.8 375.01C688.28 361
    .65 666.81 350.91 594.39 411.18C521.95 471.43 496.47 415.18 496.47 415.18C465.61 360.3 480.36 277.27 496.47 215.66C512.57 154.07 516.57 42.92 508.54 25.5C500.5
    8.11 474.42 6.17 462.92 14.79C450.71 23.99 440.13 104.53 430.74 139.34C421.34 174.14 405.26 237.1 405.26 237.1C401.23 279.96 369.03 265.23 358.3 257.17C347.58
    249.15 340.86 183.54 342.2 172.83C343.54 162.1 342.2 131.32 340.86 123.26C339.54 115.24 319.41 25.5 315.37 -5.28C311.37 -38.77 285.86 -45.45 272.45 -44.11C259
    .06 -42.8 249.65 -30.72 249.65 -18.67C249.65 -6.62 259.06 96.48 256.37 104.53C253.69 112.56 257.72 178.17 263.07 187.56C264.41 199.61 272.45 255.83 267.1 258.
    52C261.75 261.2 249.65 245.12 241.62 219.68C233.55 194.24 217.48 146.05 217.48 146.05C208.07 124.61 202.72 67.02 197.34 41.58C192 16.14 177.24 6.77 158.45 9.
    43C142.35 12.11 131.62 37.58 134.31 49.63C139.66 58.99 153.07 204.95 158.45 217C163.8 229.05 185.27 297.35 183.93 302.71C182.59 308.05 175.87 310.74 163.8 306
    .71C151.76 302.71 92.73 192.9 92.73 192.9C71.28 155.41 67.24 120.58 32.35 135.31C9.56 147.36 22.97 170.15 28.35 192.9C36.39 229.05 112.86 358.96 107.48 373.
    7C102.11 388.43 135.65 550.43 135.65 550.43C135.65 577.22 201.38 707.13 204.03 715.15C206.75 723.2 206.18 799.32 204.03 828.99C202.12 856 197.4 993.53 194.91
    1068.31C194.65 1076.33 197.34 1083.33 202.95 1089.1C208.53 1094.87 215.45 1097.81 223.48 1097.81H469.87C478.14 1097.81 485.26 1094.7 490.86 1088.64C496.5
    1082.56 499.04 1075.22 498.38 1067C490.92 872.7 481.4 702.41 480.37 674.98L480.37 674.98z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your link is dead. Please, update

Answer (score 13):

I know I am late to the party but if you have a `<path>` defined within your SVG that you'd like to move with X and Y values, you can wrap that path within another `<svg>` element, like so:

```
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <svg
    x="200"
    y="200">
    <path
      d="M32.77 32.77c-.373.372-.763.714-1.169 1.027l-7.388 7.387-7.392-7.39a12.115 12.115 0 01-2.192-2.193L4.485 21.456C-.2 16.77-.2 9.172 4.485 4.486c4.687-4.687 12.285-4.687 16.97 0l2.758 2.757 2.758-2.758C31.657-.2 39.255-.2 43.94 4.485c4.686 4.687 4.686 12.285 0 16.97L33.797 31.602c-.313.406-.655.796-1.027 1.169z"
      fill="#E84235"
      fill-rule="evenodd" />
  </svg>
</svg>
```

https://www.jotform.com/blog/better-positioning-and-transforming-with-nested-svgs/

Comment: you can't nest svg elements.

Comment: Yes, you can...

Comment: Might need a link to the spec that says this is possible then, I can't seem to find anything that explicitly explains this is actually legal.

Comment: In the 1.1 specs, `<svg>` is one of the [structural elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/intro.html#TermStructuralElement). All the structural elements except for `<use>` have the same [content model](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#SVGElement) and may be nested inside one another.

Answer (score 6):

You can also wrap the path in

```
<g transform="translate(offset_x,offset_y)"></g>
```

Comment: Thats redundant