# How to translate an SVG group by a percentage of the viewport

Tags: html, svg

I have an svg `<rect>` that is in a `<g>` (group) and I would like to scale it and then translate it by a percentage of the viewport. Most everything in svg allows the specification of units through a ridiculous number of options; e.g. px, em, %, ex, pt, pc, ... However it seems that the number specified in the translation is only pixels.

Thing is that if I have to go back and recalculate the pixel values for the translation, then my svg becomes resolution dependent. Then me, you and everyone would get sucked into a paradox. You can see why I'm a little concerned.

```
<svg>
  <g transform="scale(1, 1) translate(0, 0)">
    <rect x="45%" y="25%" height="50%" width="10%"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

http://jsbin.com/ubeqot/1/edit

Comment: Good job articulating the gravity of the situation.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Stick the `<g>` element in an inner `<svg>` element and add x and y attributes with percentage values to the inner `<svg>` element to translate it.

```
<svg>
  <svg x="10%" y="20%">
    <g transform="scale(1, 1)">
      <rect x="45%" y="25%" height="50%" width="10%"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

If you want the scale to apply first you would put the `<svg>` element inside the `<g>` instead.

Comment: And that's how you make complex stuff seemingly simple, awesome!