# SVG circle element appears as a 1/4 pie

Tags: html, svg

I tried to display a circle centered in a div.

[This is my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098397/how-to-translate-and-svg-group-by-a-percent), but the circle appears cut.

What is the problem?

```
<svg>
  <svg x="10%" y="20%">
    <g transform="scale(1, 1)">
      <circle r="100"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmeohybx/1/)

Comment: You have no `<circle>` in your code above. What is this all about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default inner `<svg>` elements clip their contents. You can set overflow="visible" if you don't want this to happen.

In addition the outer `<svg>` element has no width/height so it falls back to the defaults of 300 x 150.

If you fix it, it looks like this

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <svg x="50%" y="50%" overflow="visible">
        <g transform="scale(1,1)">
            <circle r="100"></circle>
        </g>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: My problem was also in bootstrap. Bootstrap has some parameters like svg:not(:root) { overflow: 'hidden'; }. Be careful.

Comment: I think it probably does that to work around an IE bug where IE does not do clipping by default as other UAs do.