# Center D3 Piechart in the center of a div, respecting it's dimensions

Tags: d3.js, svg, pie-chart

I'm having some difficulties with centering a piechart I created in D3 in it's parents div. I've set up a JS-fiddle right here: https://jsfiddle.net/86czgLnu/

The problem is that it overflows it's parents dimensions and I want it to scale to fit and be in the center of the parent. I found documentation about preserveAspectRatio and viewBox but wasn't able to fix it with those.

```
All the code is in the fiddle
```

Thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use percentages inside `translate`. The best idea would be using JS (D3, in your case) to get the size of the container and translate the group appropriately, by half its width.

Here is your SVG with absolute values for the translate:

```html
<div class="js-graph ct-chart">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%">
        <g transform="translate(50,50) scale(0.2)">
            <path class="slice" fill="#8c564b" d="M1.3532347130578253e-14,-221A221,221,0,1,1,-119.28791713380294,186.04137396256502L0,0Z" original-title=""></path>
            <path class="slice" fill="#c49c94" d="M-119.28791713380294,186.04137396256502A221,221,0,0,1,-210.51725450349846,-67.25686252204494L0,0Z"></path>
            <path class="slice" fill="#e377c2" d="M-210.51725450349846,-67.25686252204494A221,221,0,0,1,-4.059704139173476e-14,-221L0,0Z"></path>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

An alternative to simulate a translate by percentage is using an inner SVG, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17103928/5768908) by Robert Longson. However, it won't work, because the pie chart is drawn at the origin:

```html
<div class="js-graph ct-chart">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%">
        <svg x="50%" y="50%">
            <g transform="scale(0.2)">
                <path class="slice" fill="#8c564b" d="M1.3532347130578253e-14,-221A221,221,0,1,1,-119.28791713380294,186.04137396256502L0,0Z" original-title=""></path>
                <path class="slice" fill="#c49c94" d="M-119.28791713380294,186.04137396256502A221,221,0,0,1,-210.51725450349846,-67.25686252204494L0,0Z"></path>
                <path class="slice" fill="#e377c2" d="M-210.51725450349846,-67.25686252204494A221,221,0,0,1,-4.059704139173476e-14,-221L0,0Z"></path>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </svg>
</div>
```

PS: `scale` is part of the ["transform"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) attribute.