# How to position a "g" element SVG

Tags: css, svg, position

I have an SVG element which is an arrow into a circle : https://jsfiddle.net/seabon/806ew03a/

```
<svg version="1.1" id="layer" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"                          viewBox="15 15 102 102" style="enable-background:new 0 0 132 132;" xml:space="preserve" data-link="go_down">
            <g class="cross-circle">
                <g class="go-clockwise">
                    <circle class="st0" cx="66" cy="66" r="43.7"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g class="down">
                <polyline class="st1" points="76.4,71 66,81.4 55.6,71 "/>
                <line class="st1" x1="66" y1="81" x2="66" y2="47"/>
            </g>
</svg>
```

I would like to translate the arrow position with css. I tried to use position relative on the g element with the class "down" but it doesn't work. I tried to put a foreignObject but doesn't work too.. Does anybody have an idea ?

Comment: I don't think you can position an element in SVG via CSS. Positioning is done through attribute values and not style values.

Comment: And if I want to animate the g element without use translate() property, how can I do this ?

Comment: You can use SVG animations, e.g.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SVG Positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479591/svg-positioning)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add `transform:translate()` rules to your CSS stylesheet. This ought to work:

```css
svg .down {
  transform:translate(0,-4px);
  transition:transform 0.3s;
}
svg:hover .down {
  transform:translate(0,4px);
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     viewBox="15 15 102 102" width="200" height="200">
  <g>
    <g>
      <circle class="st0" cx="66" cy="66" r="43.7" fill="#f00"/>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g class="down">
    <polyline points="76.4,71 66,81.4 55.6,71" fill="#fff"/>
    <line x1="66" y1="81" x2="66" y2="47" stroke="#fff"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```