# Nest multiple rects inside multiple svg containers with d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to nest an individual rect inside each svg element created in the g element, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my code + Plnk;

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rKDZGG3qKA2zY4tLk4iK?p=preview)

```
var bar = g.selectAll(".barContainer")
    .data(thisData.labels)
    .enter()

  bar
    .append("svg")
    .attr("class", "barContainer")

  bar
    .insert('rect')
    .attr('width', function(d) {
      console.log(d)
      return d.value
    })
    .attr('height', 20)
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 0)
```

Currently the DOM is displaying the rect and container class on the same level, where as I would like to nest the rect inside each container.

I've tried a few things but can't seem to crack it, I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `'g'` element which you append the `svg` to and then you also append the rect to the `'g'`. You want to append the `rect` to the `svg` element you create. Something like this :

```
var bar = g.selectAll(".barContainer")
    .data(thisData.labels)
    .enter()

  var barRectSVG = bar
    .append("svg")
    .attr("class", "barContainer")

  barRectSVG 
    .insert('rect')
    .attr('width', function(d) {
      console.log(d)
      return d.value
    })
    .attr('height', 20)
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 0)
```

Updated plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/WYbjT7ekjUuopzs0H9Pi?p=preview

Comment: thanks! is it normal that I can't style each svg ".barContainer" with css so the bars won't appear on top of each other?

Comment: styling svg elements are different to styling divs etc. Youll have translate the element to position it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479591/svg-positioning