# Set X and Y value for g element of SVG

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg

I am relatively new in **SVG** drawing with **HTML5**.

What I want to do is to make a group of elements in SVG with [**g element**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g) so that all elements inside of that **g** element can work like a group and all the element's base **x** and **y** value can be received from the **upper g element**.

So, what I have done is something like this-

```html
<svg width="500" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g x="1000" y="1000">
    <title>SVG Title Demo example</title>
    <rect width="200" height="50"
    style="fill:wheat; stroke:blue; stroke-width:1px"/>
    <text style="text-anchor: middle;" class="small">My Text</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

What I expected is all the elements inside the g element will get `x="1000"` and `y="1000"` so my expected output is like this-

[image]

But I am getting this-

[image]

### Re-

I don't like to set x and y element in `text` element. I just want to set relative x and y into the `text` element if needed, but that should be relative to g element.

Can anyone help me what I need to do to achieve my target with a group in SVG?

Comment: Do you specifically want to use svg or do you just want to draw the box in html5, which has its own drawing tools (canvas)

Comment: I am using svg , not canvas

Comment: This was helpful too! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479591/svg-positioning

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`<g>` elements don't support x or y attributes. You can use a transform instead though.

I've decreased the values from 1000 to 100 as otherwise the output is outside the 500 x 300 canvas of the outer `<svg>` element.

I've provided additional x and y attributes on the text element so it appears positioned as in your example. If wanted you could put the text itself in a `<g>` element or an `<svg>` element.

```html
<svg width="500" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="translate(100, 100)">
    <title>SVG Title Demo example</title>
    <rect width="200" height="50"
    style="fill:wheat; stroke:blue; stroke-width:1px"/>
    <text x="100" y="30" style="text-anchor: middle;" class="small">My Text</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

or using an additional `<g>` element to avoid x and y on the text itself.

```html
<svg width="500" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="translate(100, 100)">
    <title>SVG Title Demo example</title>
    <rect width="200" height="50"
    style="fill:wheat; stroke:blue; stroke-width:1px"/>
    <g transform="translate(100, 30)">
        <text style="text-anchor: middle;" class="small">My Text</text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Alternatively you could use an inner `<svg>` element instead of a `<g>` element as that does support x and y attributes

```html
<svg width="500" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <svg x="100" y="100">
    <title>SVG Title Demo example</title>
    <rect width="200" height="50"
    style="fill:wheat; stroke:blue; stroke-width:1px"/>
    <text x="100" y="30" style="text-anchor: middle;" class="small">My Text</text>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: Could you add some relative merits and considerations for each of these? When is it appropriate to nest svgs? Are there performance drawbacks? What about using transform versus native x and y attributes?

Comment: I'd use none of them, instead I'd set x and y attributes on the text element. The OP for some unfathomable reason doesn't want to do things the easy way. Performance varies with browsers and platforms and graphics cards.

Comment: I have a fairly complicated setup where I have a nested selection. Imagine a table with rows and cells inside rows. Sometimes I want to re-order the rows, and I want to change the y coordinate on the row element. I had the row as a `<g>` but now its an `<svg>` and the behavior works, but it isn't pretty. Given my data structure, it would be really tricky to update the y coordinates on each of the elements separately, and would be nice if I could do it on the row...

Comment: You should probably as a separate question although you'd have to define clearly what "not pretty" means. Maybe one of my answers is for you, try them and see.

Comment: @AlexLenail I am inclined to suggest that using nested `<svg>` elements is more in the spirit of SVG: you’re effectively nesting images, and you’re creating a structure similar to what OP wants to do with the `<g>` elements. As regards doing things the easy way, I personally think applying absolute positioning attributes individually  is not doing things the easy way.